# the R programming of Roll Regression

Tags: r, regression

I have to do roll regression based on the Daily data. I use the past three weeks of daily returns as the estimation window and the regression is estimated rolling forward one week at a time generating time series estimates of beta.i only need to get beta at the end of the week every week. I know I should use the **rollapply** in **zoo** package. but I am not sure how to do.

data example:

```
 stock        day             week          y              x
 "00001"      2009-01-02     2009-01      0.89          2.45
 "00001"      2009-01-03     2009-01      1.21          1.90
 "00001"      2009-01-04     2009-01      0.12          0.89
 "00001"      2009-01-05     2009-01      1.45          2.78
 "00001"      2009-01-06     2009-01      1.98          0.98
 "00001"      2009-01-09     2009-02      3.34          1.23
 "00001"      2009-01-10     2009-02      0.12          0.89
 "00001"      2009-01-11     2009-02      1.45          2.78
 "00001"      2009-01-13     2009-02      1.98          0.98
 "00001"      2009-01-16     2009-03      3.38          0.93
 "00001"      2009-01-17     2009-03      6.56          3.90
 "00001"      2009-01-18     2009-03      5.09          3.45
 "00001"      2009-01-19     2009-03      5.89          3.78
```

Comment: You can check these links https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-August/249696.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830919/r-rollapply-lm-regression-on-zoo-matrix-objects

Comment: This example seems just like the package in zoo. But my windows is "week" instead of "day", which means i want to do only one regression every week based on the daily date. That's quite confusing for me.

Comment: more data are added and it looks much clear for my problem.

Comment: Maybe something like: `rollapply(d, width=21, by=7, FUN=function(dat) coef(lm(y ~ x, data=as.data.frame(dat))), align='right', by.column = FALSE)`, where `d` is your `zoo` time series object.

Comment: that seems ok. But the problem is  the daily data is irregular and some days the stock is not traded at stock market. so i did't know how many days the "width" and "by" should use. three weeks is quite an unsure number for all the stock in the market......

Comment: If `z` is the series you can make it regular by merging with a regular zero width series: `merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), by = "day"))` and in your function remove the `NA` valuess: `na.omit(data.frame(dat))`.

Comment: great, that seems solve the problem. my data is a little bit of huge. I will try this method soon.